# $f_n \rightarrow 0$ in $L^{1}$ implies $\exists N$ such that $\lim_{ k\rightarrow 0 }\frac{1}{2k}\int_{-1/k}^{1/k} f_N(x) dx = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f_n \geq 0$ and $f_n \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ for $n=1,2,\ldots.$
If $f_n \rightarrow 0$ in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, must there be an $N$ such that
$$
\lim_{ k\rightarrow 0 }\frac{1}{2k}\int_{-1/k}^{1/k} f_N(x) dx = 0?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consider the functions $f_n(x)=1/n \cdot \chi(x)$. Where $\chi(x)$ is (e.g.) the characteristic function of some open and bounded interval containing zero. Then zero is a Lebesgue point for each $f_n$ and hence the limit you ask for is always $1/n$.